# How to check authorizations of high frequency IoT messages

Tags: database, microservices, backend, iot

I'm running an IoT platform. In it's current state, when devices send logs or telemetry with REST or MQTT, the only limit they have is a frequency rate limit.

Now, I want to implement new limits, and more importantly per client limits. But that's require every message to check somewhere, for each limit :

- What is the limit ?
- is the limit reached ?
  For example, for a storage limit, a service would need to answer that the current plan of the client allows N Gb, and it's current usage is N' Gbs.

Implementing such a service would add a lot of calls in the backend. I don't see how can I avoid multiple database read, and writes, on each call. Are there tricks to avoid them ?

Thank you for reading,

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see how can I avoid multiple database read, and writes, on each call. Are there tricks to avoid them?

This is a question about trade-offs. You can add *caching*. And you can also adjust to check less often, it is a trade off about what is most important for you.

But doing more things in memory, e.g. counting the limits, may also be a way to speed up. But this depends on how you implement things. You need to provide more info to be able to get a more detailed answer.